# Need Python solution in extracting the data between the multiple pattern save to csv

Tags: python, regex

Can someone help me in solving this problem. I have set of Questions in the text file and i would like to extract the content available between multple regex pattern and write it to a text or csv file.

I would like to add the content of question(test data given at bottom) to a new text/csv file with ',' separator where
the first line of the output of file content looks like this

**which of the following, Fast Processor...... , They must be dual-..., similar RAM...., Fast Network...., B,Dual-homed......**

Nextline of the output text/csv file should contain
**Which of the following is....., Micro,Warm,Trojan,Virus,B,Dual-homed or dual-homing can refer to either an........**

Note: ignore .... mentioned above, used to for representing remaining content before.
the question two info in , separated.

I would like to like to implement this with regex and loop as Question number, multiple choice options, Answer and Explanation fields are like main entities for extracting the data.

**Test Data:**
QUESTION NO: 1

Which of the following is a hardware requirement that either an IDS/IPS system or a proxy server
must have in order to properly function?

A.
Fast processor to help with network traffic analysis

B.
They must be dual-homed

C.
Similar RAM requirements

D.
Fast network interface cards

Answer: B
Explanation:

Dual-homed or dual-homing can refer to either an Ethernet device that has more than one network
interface, for redundancy purposes, or in firewall technology, dual-homed is one of the firewall
architectures, such as an IDS/IPS system, for implementing preventive security.

QUESTION NO: 2

Which of the following is an application that requires a host application for replication?

A.
Micro

B.
Worm

C.
Trojan

D.

Virus

Answer: D
Explanation:

Computer viruses infect a variety of different subsystems on their hosts. A computer virus is a
malware that, when executed, replicates by reproducing itself or infecting other programs by
modifying them. Infecting computer programs can include as well, data files, or the boot sector of
the hard drive. When this replication succeeds, the affected areas are then said to be "infected".

```
import re
inFile = open("input_new.txt",encoding='utf-8')
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")
buffer1 = ""
keepCurrentSet = True
for line in inFile:
   buffer1=buffer1+(line)

buffer1=re.findall(r"(?<=QUESTION NO:\s\d\s*) (.*?) (?=A\.)", buffer1)  
outFile.write("".join(buffer1))  
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question answer text file that you have is a structured one, you can take the following approach to convert a single question answer data to a csv row,

```
import re

text = """Which of the following is a hardware requirement that either an IDS/IPS system or a proxy server must have in order to properly function?

A. Fast processor to help with network traffic analysis

B. They must be dual-homed

C. Similar RAM requirements

D. Fast network interface cards

Answer: B Explanation:

Dual-homed or dual-homing can refer to either an Ethernet device that has more than one network interface, for redundancy purposes, or in firewall technology, dual-homed is one of the firewall architectures, such as an IDS/IPS system, for implementing preventive security."""

text1 = re.sub(r'(\n+A\.)|(\n+B\.)|(\n+C\.)|(\n+D\.)', ',', text)
text1 = re.sub(r'\n+Answer:|Explanation:\n+', ',', text1)

print(text1)
```

Final output:

```
Which of the following is a hardware requirement that either an IDS/IPS system or a proxy server must have in order to properly functi
on?, Fast processor to help with network traffic analysis, They must be dual-homed, Similar RAM requirements, Fast network interface c
ards, B ,Dual-homed or dual-homing can refer to either an Ethernet device that has more than one network interface, for redundancy pur
poses, or in firewall technology, dual-homed is one of the firewall architectures, such as an IDS/IPS system, for implementing prevent
ive security.
```

As you can see, the `text` variable is holding a single question answer data (with newlines as you would get if you read that data using python from a file).

Next, what I have done is,

```
text1 = re.sub(r'(\n+A\.)|(\n+B\.)|(\n+C\.)|(\n+D\.)', ',', text)
```

the `\n+A\.` for example matches text like "A." in the multiple choice answers (`\n+` matches any newline characters preceding the multiple choice option). With the above code, we convert the MCQ option tags to `,`.

In the final step, I do this,

```
text1 = re.sub(r'\n+Answer:|Explanation:\n+', ',', text1)
```

which takes care of the actual answer and its explanation.

You can extrapolate this yourself by looping the above logic for each question in your file to get the desired output.

**EDIT:**

You can also use the following code to handle multiple questions at once:

```
import re

text = """QUESTION NO: 1

Which of the following is a hardware requirement that either an IDS/IPS system or a proxy server must have in order to properly function?

A. Fast processor to help with network traffic analysis

B. They must be dual-homed

C. Similar RAM requirements

D. Fast network interface cards

Answer: B Explanation:

Dual-homed or dual-homing can refer to either an Ethernet device that has more than one network interface, for redundancy purposes, or in firewall technology, dual-homed is one of the firewall architectures, such as an IDS/IPS system, for implementing preventive security.

QUESTION NO: 2

Which of the following is an application that requires a host application for replication?

A. Micro

B. Worm

C. Trojan

D.

Virus

Answer: D Explanation:

Computer viruses infect a variety of different subsystems on their hosts. A computer virus is a malware that, when executed, replicates by reproducing itself or infecting other programs by modifying them. Infecting computer programs can include as well, data files, or the boot sector of the hard drive. When this replication succeeds, the affected areas are then said to be "infected"."""


text1 = re.sub(r'QUESTION NO: \d+', '\n', text)
text1 = re.sub(r'(\n+A\.)|(\n+B\.)|(\n+C\.)|(\n+D\.)', ',', text1)
text1 = re.sub(r'\n+Answer:|Explanation:\n+', ',', text1)
text1 = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', text1)

print(text1)
```

This prints the following,

```
Which of the following is a hardware requirement that either an IDS/IPS system or a proxy server must have in order to properly functi
on?, Fast processor to help with network traffic analysis, They must be dual-homed, Similar RAM requirements, Fast network interface c
ards, B ,Dual-homed or dual-homing can refer to either an Ethernet device that has more than one network interface, for redundancy pur
poses, or in firewall technology, dual-homed is one of the firewall architectures, such as an IDS/IPS system, for implementing prevent
ive security.                                                                                                                         
Which of the following is an application that requires a host application for replication?, Micro, Worm, Trojan,                      
Virus, D ,Computer viruses infect a variety of different subsystems on their hosts. A computer virus is a malware that, when executed,
 replicates by reproducing itself or infecting other programs by modifying them. Infecting computer programs can include as well, data
 files, or the boot sector of the hard drive. When this replication succeeds, the affected areas are then said to be "infected".
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It absolutely works like gem for one question. But how to handle the Question1 to Question2 and iteriate it for whole file and still extract the content between the question 1 to Question 2 to line 1 of output file and question2 to question 3 to line two of output file with the loop. That is the main issue i am facing.

Comment: @BoyaRaghavendra please take a look at the updated answer and if you feel it is useful, please upvote and accept it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks @mettleap that was an absolute yes from my side. I am not a python programmer. But still you helped in resolving it :)